# jquery sortable breaks axis rule. How to fix?

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

When I use the sortable, the axis rule becomes inactive ([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/))

I want the item to be moving only horizontally. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Add `axis: x` in order to limit the drag axis:

```
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        axis: "x",
        revert: true
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/1804/)